Is there ever a manned aircraft that was successfully flown faster than the Concorde?
I've always been interested in supersonic airliners, like the Concorde. However, my question is, is Concorde really the fastest manned aircraft in the world? Had there ever been another manned aircraft successfully flown faster than the Concorde? Thanks for any answer!

Concorde was one of the fastest airliner not because it was incredibly fast, but because it was incredibly impractical, so much that we have completely given up on the idea of supersonic passenger airplanes till today. It wasn't even the fastest airplane even back in the 60s.

Before we get into a series of fastest/highest/ slowest manned/ unmanned questions, take note of the requirement to do some basic research before posting here. Wikipedia has a page dedicated to air speed records, and links to other aviation related records. FWIW, the record for fastest manned controlled flight is held by Space Shuttle Columbia at around Mach 25.

If you hover over the downvote button, one of the suggested reasons for downvoting is "lack of research". Now, I didn't downvote, but I can understand why someone would downvote a question for "lack of research" when the answer can be found using any random web search engine in less than 5 seconds.

I am curious as to why you think the Concorde is the fastest manned aircraft, or even one of the fastest?  Can you point to a website that gave you that impression?

@JörgWMittag So, can I improve anything? Because I can't delete this question anymore, so I would like to take some actions to prevent further downvoting. Thanks for your explanation, and I would very appreciate any suggestions for improvement on this post.

@MikeSowsun Well, there are many places that state Concorde is at least one of the fastest aircraft in the world. Various articles, websites, TV channels, etc... , to name a few: worlds fastest airliner, article on Concorde from the Guardian, etc.

@AircraftEnthusiast007 - There are a LOT of military aircraft that are faster than the Concorde. Going all the way back to the 1960s, and the F-106. Trivial research would discover this.

The fastest powered, crewed aircraft was the North American Aviation X-15A-2 Number 2 which reached an airspeed of 7 274 km/h corresponding to Mach 6.70 on Flight 188.
Ironically, the fastest powered, crewed aircraft is not also the fastest crewed aircraft in general. The fastest crewed aircraft is actually a glider: the Space Transportation System Orbiter OV-102 reached about 28 000 km/h corresponding to about Mach 25 on STS-2.
There are some unofficial claims that the Buran reached speeds slightly faster than that. IFF that were true, it would make Buran the fastest crew-capable aircraft: it was designed for a crew of 8–10, but its only orbital test flight was performed uncrewed, then the program was shut down before any crewed flights happened.
